# wget 'https://www.amazon.cn/dp/0132269937' gave me the incorrect page comparing to chrome

Tags: google-chrome, curl, wget

When I using Chrome to open the link https://www.amazon.cn/dp/0132269937, Chrome gave me the correct web page. But when I use wget or curl ,it gave me the 503 error.What's the difference between them ? I guess the root cause is COOKIE,how to figure out it?

Comment: cookies and user-agent are your first good bets, compare with the browsers dev tools how its requests look like then compare with curl/wget and adjust

Comment: Thanks, I know how to do then~

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try setting chrome's user agent in the curl/wget request.

For example for curl:

curl -A "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_3) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/54.0.2403.89 Safari/537.36" https://www.amazon.cn/dp/0132269937